# download zip file using Rest API responding null file immediately

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot API for downloading zip file, when i hit rest API in IE or chrome, API responding with file name as null, with no content, if try to hit the same api again after few seconds, the file getting downloaded.
how to fix this issue.

Please help.

Thanks
Daya

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting questions is SO :)

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the filename was set after the content(stream) was written to response, once content was written the control return back to client - before filename was set to the header.